# Android - Changing GridView text color and styling

Tags: android, gridview

I am very new to android development. I have a activity with a GridView. I need to change GridView's text color and change each row's background color. How can I do this ?

Thank You in advance.

DineshNS

Answer (score 0):

GridView is just a layout control, you need to change text and background color of the components you have put in GridView (Maybe ImageView or TextView)